# Jenkins Pipeline Jenkinsfile load external groovy class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Could anyone advice on how to load external groovy class into the Jenkinsfile ?
In general, I would like to build instance by passing parameters via constructor.
Sample code below.

*Jenkinsfile*

```
stage('Demo stage') {
   //missing part  
  
}
```

Tools.groovy

```
public class Demo {
     String message;
     
     Demo(String message) {
        this.message=message;
     }
     

    public void print(def script) {
        script.sh "echo " + message
    }
}
```

Comment: We are using various files for various tasks. you can simply call 
def  module = new fileName() and use it as a class without the class def. 
I have not found a way to create a non standard constructor with paramters yet.  you have to assign the fields after init.

Answer (score 3):

It requires a helper function to do so.

#### Tools.groovy

```
public class Demo {
    String message;
     
    Demo(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void print(def script) {
        script.sh "echo " + message
    }
}

Demo createDemo(String message) {
    new Demo(message)
}

return this
```

#### Jenkinsfile

```
stage('Demo stage') {
   steps {
       script {
           Object lib = load 'path/to/Tools.groovy'
           Object demo = lib.createDemo('a demo')
           demo.print(this)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This works for single class but not classes that uses inheritance extending another class. I

Comment: I get a nullptr exception when trying to call `lib.createDemo(...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
mytools = load 'Tools.groovy'
public class Demo {

}
return new Demo() ;
```

In your `Tools.groovy` you have to have a return statement... Since you are looking to call functions inside a class , you have to return new Demo() at the end ,this would return reference of the object to mytools.

In addition to this you can always use groovy class loader.

Comment: Per the question, they want to load a class, not an instance. Class loader isn't permitted in default untrusted code.

Answer (score 0):

if your external groovy file is in the same repository that JenkinsFile resides you can simply use "load" as showen below

```
mytools = load 'Tools.groovy'
```

If its in another repo, you need to checkout scm before loading the groovy file as below

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'jenkins-scripts']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '******', url: 'https://github.com/jenkins_scripts.git']]]
```

Comment: `load` works fine for functions, but doesn't seem to be able to handle classes (per the question).

Comment: I tried for a while to figure out how to have a class in a script that is loaded, but, as you said, it doesn't appear very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `evaluate readTrusted`:

```
SCMData = evaluate readTrusted("shared/git_info.groovy")
```